# How to color entire screen solid color in Win32

Tags: c, winapi, background-color

```
    RECT rect;
    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    LockWindowUpdate(hwnd);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, hbrush);
```

This is my previous attempt which did nothing. Just to be clear, I am trying to color the whole screen a solid color.

Comment: As Chris mentions in the end of his answer, the best way to do this is to create your own window the size of the entire screen, and paint it green. That way, when you remove your window, the desktop will get repainted back to normal, and also other repainting won't interfere with your window. Generally speaking, you shouldn't paint on HDCs of windows that you don't own. But it's perhaps worth trying it anyhow just so you can see what problems it has: for example, wait a minute and you'll see the clock in the status bar redraw itself.

Comment: I agree. The best way to do anything is with the least violation of other progams' privacy and with the least chance of a clash in the case that another program has the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works using GDI (which you seem to be using):

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HDC screenDC = GetDC(NULL); //NULL gets whole screen
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0)); //create brush
    SelectObject(screenDC, brush); //select brush into DC
    Rectangle(screenDC, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)); //draw rectangle over whole screen
    //clean up stuff here
    return 0;
}
```

This is meant as an example, not a robust solution. For example, selecting the previous brush back into the DC is always a good idea. So is releasing the DC. Another option is to have a fullscreen window sitting over top of everything that you can use to draw onto.

Answer (score 1):

Create a full screen window (not just maximised but covering the whole workspace for mutliple monitors) and paint it white.

This is what other full screen graphics apps (games, screen savers, etc) do.